# Analytics tracking in AS2 flash movie?

Tags: flash, google-analytics, actionscript-2

I've got an AS2 flash movie that I need to add Google Analytics tracking into. The only classes I can find are for AS3, do you know of any class method to track in AS2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the google analytics javascript API to track events.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html